# Remove text+ pattern from txt file

Tags: regex, powershell, command-line, command, prompt

I am looking for solution how to remove text specified in pattern.txt from another file acc.txt (or acc.html).

```
<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
<tr>
<td style="border-bottom-color: #d0d0d0; border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-width: 1px; background-color: #eaeaea;"><!-- F1E896 -->
<font style="font-size: 13px;"><b>{.*(everything until meeting <blockquote>}
<blockquote>
{ .{1,5}? (any letters/space characters/tabs -size maximum 5)}
</blockquote>
</td>
</tr>
</table><br>
<br>
```

It should work to ignore those characters. I would prefer using prompt. I know that working on .html files is not that easy how it looks like, if we just save it as txt does it make a difference?

**Edit:** probably it would work for

```
<table {skip everything to first met}<blockquote>{max 5 letters}<blockquote>{skip everyhing to <br>
```

Comment: Saving the file as .txt doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Is the HTML the pattern you want to remove, or the text you want the pattern to be removed from? Also, what have you tried so far? SO is not a place where other people write code for you.

Answer (score 0):

Save the pattern in a file, e. g. "c:\pattern.txt":

```powershell
(?<=<b>).*(?=<blockquote>)|(?<=<blockquote>).*(?=<\/blockquote>)
```

Load the pattern and the text file using the [Get-Content](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849787.aspx) cmdlet and replace it with an empty string:

```powershell
$content = (Get-Content 'c:\acc.txt' -raw) 
$pattern = (Get-Content 'c:\pattern.txt' -raw)

[regex]::Replace($content, $pattern, '',`
     [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::Multiline `
     -bor [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::Singleline)
```

Now you can pipe the output to [Out-File](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849882.aspx) or [Set-Content](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849828.aspx) cmdlet.